# JQuery Draggable - Drag Parent Div

Tags: jquery, draggable

Can anyone tell me how to make the parent div of a draggable div, drag along with it?

I have a div "window", and a div "titleBar". When I drag the titleBar, I want the window to drag along with it. Just how the JQuery dialog behaves.

Thanks.

Comment: why not making the parent draggable?

Comment: Because I don't want the window to drag if the use clicks/drags the window area. I only want to drag the window when the title bar area is clicked/dragged.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer.

The options "cancel" and "handle" passed to the draggable() call allows you to cancel dragging on elements, and restrict start dragging on elements. Example:

```
window.draggable({
    cancel: ".titleBarButton, .titleBarButtons",
    handle: ".titleBar",
})
```